# Invalid mode '+6000' with find -perm

Tags: find

I followed an instruction to prepare LPIC and encounter such a find instruction

```
$ sudo find / -perm +6000 -type f
[sudo] password for Christine:
/lib64/dbus-1/dbus-daemon-launcher-helper
/home/Christine/bigprogram.sh
/sbin/pam_timestamp_check
/sbin/netreport
/sbin/unix_chkpwd
[...]
$
```

but when I tried ,

```
me@host:~$ sudo find / -perm +6000 -type f
find: invalid mode ‘+6000’
```

the book is 2015 version [LPIC-1: Linux Professional Institute Certification Study Guide: Christine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119021189)

How could I enable `+6000` working on Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 3):

According to man pages of [find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/find.1.html) ***perm +mode*** is deprecated

```
-perm +mode
              This is no longer supported (and has been deprecated since 2005).  Use -perm /mode instead.
```

You can try:-

```
find / -perm /6000 -type f
```

Comment: what does + or / mean here?

Comment: The correct link to `man find` for 18.10 is http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/find.1.html .